# How to create a reusable Dialog Fragment?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, reusability

How to create a reusable dialog fragment that can be used by multiple activities in an application. Also additionally each activity that uses the Dialog fragment should be able to modify details of the dialog example: "Title" , "Icon" etc.

Answer (score 2):

By default Fragments nature is to be reused, all you need to do is create a fragment flexible enough to populate it's content based on parameters passed within arguments.
You can use the method:

> Fragment.setArguments(Bundle bundle)

To pass into the fragment the list of things that might affect the component, for example(Title, Description, etc...).
Within the fragment there's a method you can call:

> Fragment.getArguments()

Which returns the list of arguments passed by the time you called this fragment. Based on your needs you could either just add simple content into elements or even set different layouts for the very same Fragment, by doing a validation as follows(within Fragments onCreateView):

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
int layoutId = args.getInt("inflateLayoutId");
return inflater.inflate(layoutId, null);
```

Of course you must take all the precautions to avoid NPE, but this is a brief idea of how to make a Fragment reusable..

Hope it helps!

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

The Fragment class can be used many ways to achieve a wide variety of results. For getting a resuable `DialogFragment` you need to write it as a seperate class, but for modifying the details `DialogFragment` don't allows you to argumented constructors. So you can modify the details by using 
`setArguments(Bundle) & getArguments(Bundle)`:

Example:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();

args.putInt("num", num);
f.setArguments(args);
```

In `DialogFragment` get the arguments by using this:

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments()
```

For more details check this [`link`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).